# How to change admin panel port on Asus RT-N66U Black Knight Wireless Router

Tags: networking, router

I am able to access the admin panel at the default IP address of this router (192.168.1.1), but I would like to change the admin panel to be accessed at another port. Currently, it is on port 80, while I would like to have an external web server accessed on port 80. How do I change the admin panel login to be on another port, such as 8080?

Comment: Unless the router supports third-party firmware this won't be possible.

Comment: We had this configuration formerly with the default firmware, but we had to do a reset.

Comment: Why would port 80 on IP 192.168.1.1 affect you having an internal web server being accessible on port 80... Your web server will either be accessed via a different internal IP 192.168.1.x or your external IP which should not be bringing up your router web interface?

Comment: Charles, we will also need to access the web server externally. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah sorry. Yep Ramhound would appear to be correct, couple of supported third party firmwares that enable this to be changed but with stock firmware it is not an option.

Comment: @JakeWasdin - Are you running the OEM firmware or a third-party firmware.

Comment: Ramhound, I am running OEM firmware. I'll add also that I don't know how it was configured before, but it was accessible at a port like 192.168.1:8443 and not port 80.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do anything special, as long as you don't want to access the admin interface from the external Internet.

- Turn on port forwarding for port 80 and route to your webserver
- Try accessing 192.168.1.1:80 *(note that the router's admin interface still works)*
- Try accessing your router through its external IP *(your webserver should come up)*

Comment: This is the correct method for what the OP is doing. There is nothing special that needs to be done but port forwarding of port 80/TCP to whatever the internal IP address of the webserver is. From the outside port 80 is not open for router administration, no external access is allowed at all by default (but can be enabled on port 8080 by default, configurable).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [Tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29), an alternative firmware. There are several Tomato mods out there, depending on your needs you could use [Shibby](http://tomato.groov.pl/) or Toastman.

Describing how to flash a new firmware is our of scope here, but here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/joshenders/3941269) to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would strongly recommend ***against*** doing this:

1. Login to the router from your LAN.
2. In the left column click on "Administration"
3. Find the option "Enable Web Access from WAN" select **Yes** and click the Apply button.
4. You can also change the default portnumber from 8080 (perhaps in your case it says 8443 here) to something else. But I'd stick to 8080 if I were you.

The helptext of this option says:

*This feature allows you to configure the wireless router via the Internet. The default port is 8080 and you can use [http://[[WAN IP]]:8080](http://asus.com) or [http://[[DDNS name]]:8080](http://asus.com) to launch the wireless router's web user interface.*

Note that this way port 80 remains available to be forwarded to a webserver on your LAN.

**Also: make sure you have a very strong password for the login account as this exposes the router's setup UI to the big bad world.**

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your public ip is 1.2.3.4

First, you have your router at 192.168.1.1
Its admin panel is running at port 80, so you can access it with "192.168.1.1:80" using your browser, or just "192.168.1.1" (because the browser will visit port 80 by default).
From outside, you can access this by just doing "1.2.3.4(:80)".

Now you have your web service running at 192.168.1.2
Its service also uses port 80, so you can access it with "192.168.1.2:80"

From LAN, you can access both different services by doing "192.168.1.1" and "192.168.1.2".

Your router probably automatically forwarded its own port 80 to the outside, so you can access it from outside by going to 1.2.3.4 by default. But your router is also just a device in your network.

So when you entered a rule that says local ip = 192.168.1.2, local port = 80, port range = 80

This basically means 1.2.3.4:80 -> 192.168.1.2:80

Now you can enter a different rule local ip = 192.168.1.1, local port = 80, port range = 8080

This will make possible 1.2.3.4:8080 -> 192.168.1.1:80